# Subplot a groupby then Plot by groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to plot a categorical data which is **description**:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-09-14 00:00:22',
                                '2018-09-14 00:01:46',
                                '2018-09-14 00:01:56',
                                '2018-09-14 00:01:57',
                                '2018-09-14 00:01:58',
                                '2018-09-14 00:02:05'],
                        'userID': [33, 33, 33, 20, 20, 20],
                        'device': ['LIGHT', 'LIGHT', 'FAN', 'LIGHT', 'FAN', 'FAN'],
                        'description': ['ON', 'DIM', 'ON', 'ON', 'ON', 'OFF']})

data_df
```

What I want to is to plot them by grouping the **'device'** but before that I want to subplot by rows the **'userID'** so that they are separated each by **'userID'** and each line plots are grouped based on the **'device'** name.

I also tried grouping by and plot but it say my **description** is not numeric since it is categorical. Date is the x-axis, and description as y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to plot the `description` of `userID` and `device` groups over time. Obviously, `description` needs to be converted to a numeric variable, so I took the liberty of coding ON as 1, DIM as 0.5, and OFF as 0. The following code should solve your problem.

```
data_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['Date'])

def desc_num(x):
    if x == 'ON':
        return 1
    elif x == 'DIM':
        return 0.5
    else:
        return 0

data_df['desc_num'] = data_df['description'].apply(desc_num)    

## Creating groups of `userID` and `device`
groups = data_df.groupby(['userID', 'device'])

for g in groups:
    plt.plot(g[1]['Date'], g[1]['desc_num'])
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('description Status')
    plt.title('Time Series of userID: {0}, for device: {1}'.format(g[1]['userID'][0], g[1]['device'][0]))
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Output (you should see such a plot for every subgroup):

[image]

Comment: Hmmm I need them as strings, because they are categorical.

Comment: Also all line plots of devices must be present per userID.

Comment: What kind of a plot were you looking for?

Comment: Line plot, you see I want to check the behavior of these devices per User. I need all devices in one User to see if there's some similar behavior. The original dataframe has a lot more device and description.

Comment: I also guess it is possible to subplot by rows each User.